# Migrate authorize.net data from one account to another account

Tags: authorize.net

Can we migrate data from one authorize.net account to another authorize.net account? If yes, what all information can be migrated/moved to the new account?

I have figured out that Customer Profiles, Customer Payment Profiles, Customer Shipment Address can be migrated using API's. Subscriptions cannot be migrated since they will not work after migration. Is there a way we can migrate Transactions or any other information to the new account?

Comment: This is a question for Authorize.Net support

Comment: Thanks John for the suggestion. I have already reached out to them, but in the meantime thought of raising a question in stackoverflow.